# angularjs constant how to use Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wondering what's wrong with this snippet

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.constant('_START_REQUEST_', '_START_REQUEST_');
            app.constant('_END_REQUEST_', '_END_REQUEST_');
            app.config(function($httpProvider, _START_REQUEST_, _END_REQUEST_) {

            });
```

it give me

Unknown provider: START_REQUEST from myApp

Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it is the way you have named your constants that is causing the problem.

If you change `_START_REQUEST_` & `_END_REQUEST_` to `START_REQUEST` & `END_REQUEST` it works.

It must be something to do with the `_` at the start of the name.

This may be a bug or there may be a reason for it, but as it stands I don't know why angular doesn't accept the names like that.

**Demo with no errors in console http://jsbin.com/UZaquNu/1/edit**